# Verification of the approach on finding the limit of $x_n$ as $n\to\infty$ given $x_{n+1} = \sqrt[k]{5x_n}$ where $x_1 = \sqrt[k]{5}, k\in\Bbb N$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Let $x_n$ denote a sequence, $n\in\Bbb N$:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_{n+1} = \sqrt[k]{5x_n}\\
> x_1 = \sqrt[k]{5}\\
> k\in\Bbb N
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{x_n}
> $$

I would like to verify my approach on finding the limit, which doesn't seem very natural and potentially find a simpler one. I've started with writing down several first terms:
$$
x_1 = \sqrt[k]{5}\\
x_2 = \sqrt[k]{5\sqrt[k]{5}}\\
x_3 = \sqrt[k]{5\sqrt[k]{5\sqrt[k]{5}}}\\
\dots
$$

Rewrite as:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 5^{1\over k}\\
x_2 &= \left(5\cdot 5^{1\over k}\right)^{1\over k} = 5^{\frac{k+1}{k^2}}\\
&\cdots\\
x_n &= 5^{\frac{k^{n-1} + k^{n-2} + \cdots + 1}{k^n}}
\end{align}
$$

This is hardly readable using powers in mathjax. Rewrite:
$$
\log_5 x_n = \frac{k^{n-1} + k^{n-2} + \cdots + 1}{k^n}
$$

Nominator is a regular geometric series:
$$
1 + k + \cdots + k^{n-2} + k^{n-1} = \frac{k^n - 1}{k - 1}
$$

Thus:
$$
\frac{k^n - 1}{k - 1} \cdot \frac{1}{k^n} = \frac{k^n}{(k - 1)k^n} -  \frac{1}{(k-1)k^n}\tag 1
$$

Since $a^x$ is continuous we may consider the limit of $(1)$:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{k^n}{(k - 1)k^n} -  \frac{1}{(k-1)k^n}\right) = \frac{1}{k-1}
$$
Which implies:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \sqrt[k-1]{5}
$$

Is it the right way to approach this problem? Could it be simplified? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x_2 = \sqrt[k]{5\sqrt[k]{5}} \ge \sqrt[k]{5} = x_1$. If we assume that $x_{n} \ge x_{n-1}$, it follows
$\sqrt[k]{5x_{n}} \ge \sqrt[k]{5x_{n-1}}$, or $x_{n+1} \ge x_n$. Induction implies  that $(x_n)_n$ is increasing.

We have $x_1 = \sqrt[k]{5} \le \sqrt[k-1]{5}$. If we assume $x_n \le \sqrt[k-1]{5}$, we get $$x_{n+1} = \sqrt[k]{5x_n} \le \sqrt[k]{5\sqrt[k-1]{5}} = \left(5\cdot 5^{\frac1{k-1}}\right)^{1/k} = \sqrt[k-1]{5}$$
Induction implies that $x_n \le \sqrt[k-1]{5}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

The sequence $(x_n)_n$ is increasing and bounded from above so it converges to some $L = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$.

Letting $n\to\infty$ in the relation $x_{n+1} = \sqrt[k]{5x_n}$ gives
$$L = \sqrt[k]{5L} \implies L(L^{k-1}-5) = 0$$

It cannot be $L = 0$ because $x_n \ge x_1 =\sqrt[k]{5}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $L = \sqrt[k-1]{5}$.

Comment: Thank you! Induction is indeed a better suit here.